# How to make transparent WUA app just like new windows 10 calculator is on hold?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-10-universal, transparent

New windows 10 calculator looks great with its new transparent UI. How to make same to my own app? I tried to find answer but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transparency effect is called "Acrylic" and is part of [Microsoft's new design language](http://fluent.microsoft.com/).

When and how to use it [is explained on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic).

In a nutshell, you simply need to apply an `AcrylicBrush` on whatever surface you want to make transparent. The `BackgroundSource` allows you to tell whether you want the transparency to be relative to your app (you'll see your background controls) or to the desktop (you'll see the wallpaper/other windows).

Note that it's a bit early to build applications based on this API, as it's only available on Insider builds of Windows with the preview SDK, and is subject to change. Though if you want your app to be ready for launch, it's a good thing to start playing with it.

Comment: Thanks. Information U gave is great and just that I needed. Thanks ones again!